# RSA - How to check for public key info?

Tags: c#, arrays, rsa

I encrypt and decrypt data using the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` in C#, and when I generate a new keypair, I return the private key to the caller of the method and then save the public key to a homemade PKI (just a dictionary with the keyBlob and a unique identifier).

My problem is this: since I need to store the public key, I don't want to accidentally store a private key in the PKI. However, since I also need to actually write the private key to a file, I am working with byte arrays exported with the `ExportCspBlob` method.

My question:
How do I ensure, by checking the `byte[]` that I parse into my `StoreKey` method, that it is in fact a public key and it does not contain private key information?

For clarification, here is the relevant code:

```
public static bool StoreKey(byte[] publicKeyParameters, string uniqueIdentifier)
{
    bool success = false;
    if (!keyCollection.ContainsKey(uniqueIdentifier))
    {
        if (!keyCollection.ContainsValue(publicKeyParameters))
        {
            keyCollection.Add(uniqueIdentifier, publicKeyParameters);
            success = true;
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

And the `GenerateKeys` method:

```
public static byte[] GenerateKeys(string uniqueIdentifier)
{
    byte[] privateKeyBlob;

    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(4096))
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] publicKey = rsa.ExportCspBlob(false);

            privateKeyBlob = rsa.ExportCspBlob(true);

            PublicKeyInfrastructure.StoreKey(publicKey, uniqueIdentifier);
        }
        finally
        {
            //// Clear the RSA key container, deleting generated keys.
            rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        }
    }
    return privateKeyBlob;
}
```

Since I am working on two different classes, I would like to abstain from initializing a `RSACryptoServiceProvider` in my PKI, just to import the key and check for it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN, the output of `ExportCspBlob` is compatible with CAPI, and according to the documentation for the CAPI [BLOBHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the first byte represents the key type. Specifically, if the first byte is 0x07, it's a private key, whereas 0x06 is a public key.

Comment: So I have looked at some different generated keys, it seems that the public keys I generate share the same bit pattern for the first 20 indexes in the array. Now, when I want to initialize a byte array and I got new byte[ 0x00, 0x00, 0x03...] how do I write 164 bits? 1x64?. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. May be worth making this a separate question.

Comment: I just don't want to flood the servers with my stupid questions :D But I got it sorted out, thanks :)